# RSS Feed XMLDataSource Filter RSS Items

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, rss

Given a standard RSS feed being consumed in an XMLDataSource, what would be the best way of filtering the RSS feed to show only items where the RSS feed item description contains a particular term?

e.g I wish to filter the following RSS feed where the description contains a certain team name say  'Liverpool'

http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=9dae054b43e8ded5a10a659c39c72f49&_render=rss

My code to set the XML datasource is as follows:

```
 HomeDataSource.DataFile = "http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=9dae054b43e8ded5a10a659c39c72f49&_render=rss";
        HomeDataSource.XPath = "rss/channel/item";
        HomeListView.DataSourceID = "HomeDataSource";
        HomeListView.DataBind();
```

The output of the above code is displayed using the following source code:

```
 <asp:ListView ID="HomeListView" runat="server">
                <LayoutTemplate>
                    <ul>
                        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                    </ul>
                </LayoutTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <li><a target="_blank" href="<%#XPath("link")%>">
                        <%#XPath("title")%></a>
                    </li>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
```

Many thanks in advance for any advice offered.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you will face is the different feed types, Atom, RSS 1.0/2.0 etc, use different names for certain common fields. You could create a custom DataSource control to expose a System.ServiceModel.Syndication SyndicationFeed object for binding or read the feed in the code behind and bind the SyndicationFeed or SyndicationFeed.Items as the ListViews DataSource.